# Where is the main verb in "the training necessary to enable them to carry out their duties"?

Tags: sentence-construction

*the training necessary to enable them to carry out their duties*

If the sentence is correct than where is main verb or auxiliary verb?

Here is the link of the sentence :

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/carry-out_1

Comment: Definitions need not be full sentences. Just concentrate on the use of "carry out" the dictionary is trying to show. Next time you ask a question, it is good to give all the information in the body of the question. This will give you more chances to receive adequate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Sentences begin with a capital letter and end with a period or question mark. Your example isn’t punctuated as a sentence. Because it came from a dictionary, and we can see the same fragments in many other places in that dictionary, we can conclude it was probably intentional and not hasty writing or a typo.

It’s not a sentence, so it doesn’t follow the rules of a sentence.